# python 3 symlinked to python 2 - how to undo

Tags: python

Running brew doctor gave me the error recently that python 3 is symlinked to python.  And when I type python - it does load python 3.4 interpreter.
I'm not sure how it happened. I did recently changed the default installed python with virtualenv to python3 (most projects are python 3) with :

```
export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=python3
```

would this have changed the symlink and what's the best way to change back as

```
export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=python
```

didn't fix it, although I suspect that's because it's already symlinked. (I've used brew to install python 2.7 and python 3 and these were previously fine).

(if changing the virtualenv setting has caused the issue is there another way to make the default python3 without causing the symlink issue?)

Comment: I would suggest to purge brew-python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update brew, then prune any stale links and then re-link Python 2.

1. `brew update`
2. `brew upgrade` (optional, but highly recommended)
3. `brew prune`
4. `brew unlink python && brew link python`

Comment: Thanks. on step 4 I get the error No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python2 . I instead tried step 4. with just python in place of python2. Unfortunately that didn't work as the issue is still there.

Comment: Sorry, should be simply `brew unlink python`

Comment: Thanks that worked - would setting VIRTUALENV_PYTHON above cause the issue - or is that ok to use? redoing it to python3 doesn't seem to cause an issue so it looks ok

Comment: Not that's fine. I doesn't effect the system-wide Python.