# Trouble with psycopg2 setting up django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, virtualenv, psycopg2

I'm trying to set up a Django app using a postgresql server (to eventually use with GeoDjango for GIS). I'm on a mac running OSX 10.11 and am running python 3.5 in a virtualenv. I've gone through all the installtion of postgresql, pyscopg2 etc and am trying to run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But when I do I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
import psycopg2 as Database
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2     module: dlopen(/Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/me/.python3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

I've found a couple of stackoverflow threads on this error but none of the solutions seem to help at all.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Edit: brew doctor output

```
Warning: python is symlinked to python3
This will confuse build scripts and in general lead to subtle breakage.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
/Users/me/.python3env/bin/python-config

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the postgres and psycopg2 properly? If so, did you migrate your newly created database?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, edited the question as the command I'm actually running which gives that error is the migration! And as far as I can tell everything should be installed properly

Comment: There is tons of info on this issue around stackoverflow. To be able to pinpoint to a solution better, are you running Postgres via Homebrew or Postgres.app?

Comment: Homebrew, yes I've tried to find a solution on a few threads but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you run `brew doctor`?

Comment: Yes, added the output above - not sure what might be related

Comment: How did you install Python 3? It looks like you did not install it via Homebrew. Can you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32501013/5110568)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127011/discussion-between-thenaturalist-and-nowandthen98).